# Behavior of Enter key when pressed in address bar with URL containing '#'

Tags: url, browser, hash, request

I have a link like this: **http://....../index?spid=1#tid=2&cmno=17** which will render an index page and move window position to top of the comment no.17 (cmno=17). It works normally.
But in other browser like IE, Firefox, when I was in that page, and focus mouse on the address bar then press enter again without changing URL, the page does not refresh. While in Chrome, when I do the same thing, the page is refreshed.
Is that normal behavior and difference between Chrome vs IE, Firefox? Or it's just my website's source code problem? Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looking for answers do you have one?

Comment: Yes, I found it by myself, please look below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked chromium and this is the answer:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12952
So it is intentional UI design.

Comment: Did you gave a solution or a reason to not solving this issue?

Comment: Both, it's behavior of Chrome, and the hash is in the spec, so I can't fix it by myself.